# How can I plot a pandas dataframe where x = month and y = frequency of text?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following dataset:

| Date | ID | Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-2-2 | 1 | Apple |
| 2021-2-2 | 1 | Pear |
| 2021-2-2 | 1 | Apple |
| 2021-2-2 | 2 | Pear |
| 2021-2-2 | 2 | Pear |
| 2021-2-2 | 2 | Apple |
| 2021-3-2 | 3 | Apple |
| 2021-3-2 | 3 | Apple |

I have removed duplicate "Fruit" based on ID (There can only be 1 apple per ID number but multiple apples per a single month).  And now I would like to generate multiple scatter/line plots (one per "Fruit" type) with the x-axis as month (i.e. Jan. 2021, Feb. 2021, Mar. 2021, etc) and the y-axis as frequency or counts of "Fruit" that occur in that month.

If I could generate new columns in a new sheet in Excel that I could then plot as x and y that would be great too. Something like this for Apples specifically:

| Month | Number of Apples |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 2021 | 0 |
| Feb 2021 | 2 |
| Mar 2021 | 1 |

I've tried the following which let me remove duplicates but I can't figure out how to count the number of Apples in the Fruit column that occur within a given timeframe (month is what I'm looking for now) and set that to the y-axis.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_excel('FruitExample.xlsx',
                    usecols=("A:E"), sheet_name=('Data'))


df_Example = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["ID Number", "Fruit"], keep="first")

df_Example.plot(x="Date", y=count("Fruit"), style="o")
plt.show()
```

I've tried to use groupby and categorical but can't seem to count this up properly and plot it. Here is an example of a plot that would be great.

[[image: Example Plot]]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the dates are in datetime format

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then create a column for month-year,

```
df['Month-Year']=df['Date'].dt.to_period('M') #M for month
new_df=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Month-Year','Fruit'])['ID'].count())
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Make sure to change back to datetime as seaborn can't handle 'period' type

```
new_df['Month-Year']=new_df['Month-Year'].apply(lambda x: x.to_timestamp())
```

Then plot,

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='Month-Year',y='ID',data=new_df,hue='Fruit')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When I try to run the section "Create a column for month-year" I am able to run the first line of code and succesfully create the new column for month-year. However, running the second line of code gives me a "SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer, col_indexer] = value instead.  I think I understand why this is happening but I can't figure out how to use .loc correctly here.

Comment: Just edited. Seems I had to split up the reset.index part. Also fixed a typo and made sure to convert the period to datetime format as seaborn apparently can't handle it. Does it work now?

Comment: Thank you. It does work now but this is plotting "ID"  vs "Date" for each fruit. I actually need to plot "amount of fruit" vs "Date" for each fruit. I'm guessing I need to add some value_counts type code in here to get that and use it as the "y" value for the plot.

Comment: Ohhh okay! Hope that works then. I thought the .count() in groupby would have done the trick (and the column with the counts should be labeled ID in the df after groupby)